# Pass form contents to a controller, do calculations, then pass back multiple results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that was scaffolded from a model. I need to retrieve the values from the "editfor" helper tags, do a bunch of calculations, then pass back the results (multiple)back to the view. I created a small example to clarify.

```
public class OpticalcTestViewModel
{
    public double OD_Sphere { get; set; }
    public double OD_Cylinder { get; set; }
    public int Axis { get; set; }
}
```

Which creates this scaffold:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>OpticalcTestViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OD_Sphere, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OD_Sphere, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OD_Sphere, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OD_Cylinder, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OD_Cylinder, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OD_Cylinder, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Axis, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Axis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Axis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   }

    <div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

     @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      }
```

This is my controller:

```
public class OpticalcTestController : Controller
{
    // GET: OpticalcTest
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

How do I get the values out of the "editfor" boxes, perform calculations on them, then pass the results of those calculations(multiple results, not just one)back to some labels in the view?

This is such a simple thing in winforms, which is what I usually work with, but I'm at my wits end trying to find an answer to this. It seems like the other 9,000 results I get from searches are always about writing the data (as a whole model) to a database. This will have no database. It's just a form that takes numeric values, does calculations and spits out results.

To be more specific, how would I pull those values into the controller, Add sphere to cylinder, then add cylinder to axis and pass back both results separately to labels (or some other way to view them)?

Thanks,
R

Comment: Do note it is perfectly feasible to do mathematical calculations in JavaScript, so you don't necessarily have to send the values back to the server at all to run calculations on them. Unless of course you have some specific reason (such as hiding your calculations from competitors) for putting them on the server.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but there's going to be a lot of calculations and I need good debugging and the ability to write test cases.

Comment: If you do need o do this on the server, then you should consider using ajax to post the values and update the DOM with the returned value to improve performance

Comment: @rmnrdi - You can also write [unit tests](https://raygun.com/blog/javascript-unit-testing-frameworks/) in JavaScript. It is true the language isn't quite as easy to debug or as robust as C#, but if you perform the calculations in the browser they will execute faster than sending values across the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an HttpPost method to accept the model from the view and access the properties bound to the EditorFor helper elements as maccettura wrote.

Then you can perform calculations like so inside the method:

```
double sphereRadius = model.OD_Sphere / 2; // demo calc
```

Are the calculation results going to be on the same view? Same model?
Assuming yes, I'd recommend new model properties for the calculated values, then bind those to your view. You can use Razor to show/hide the inputs and calculated values as required.

Example assuming you use the calculation above w/ a new model property:

```
public class OpticalcTestViewModel
{
    public double OD_Sphere { get; set; }
    public double OD_Cylinder { get; set; }
    public int Axis { get; set; }

    public double sphereRadius { get; set; } // new calculated property
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OpticalcTestViewModel model)
{
    double sphereRadius = model.OD_Sphere / 2; // demo calc
    model.sphereRadius = sphereRadius;
    return View(model);
}
```

Note that if you attempt to edit a model property which has already been bound to the view, it will retain its old value. That's because the value is actually retained in the ModelState, and the default model binder will check there first and use values if they exist. To override this you'll have to clear the ModelState property, but that gets a little messy.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! That's what I needed to know. One last thing. I have quite a few calculations to perform. Is the controller the best place for that? Would the ViewModel be a better place for that? Or should I pass the model into a separate class that performs all the calculations and then returns the model?

Comment: Strictly a matter of preference. Mine is to keep the controllers light, so I create static Factory methods to do things like calculations and database calls.

Comment: There is no such thing as ` ViewState` in mvc. What your referring to is `ModelState`

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is add an action to your controller that accepts a parameter of type `OpticalcTestViewModel` and is tagged with the `[HttpPost]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OpticalcTestViewModel model)
{
    //perform calculations
    return View(model);
}
```

As you notice above, after you have performed calculations you will need to modify the `model` variable to add in your new calculations, then you just send it back to the view (`return View(model)`).

Your form in the view is performing a POST by default. Since you have no actions that are capable of handling a POST request, you will never be able to service those calls.  The above code should fix all that.

In either case, I would *highly* recommend taking some more tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  Microsoft has a couple of decent tutorials, but there are also a lot of free resources online.

Comment: Thanks maccettura. I've tried working through tutorials in the past, but it always seems to end the same way. Me, bored out of my mind, the code broken and more questions then answers. I keep doing them, but I haven't found many that I get a lot from. Unfortunately, learning by tutorial is really sub-optimal, because it doesn't allow for questions. While we're on the topic of tutorials. Any suggestions? Any tutorials that really gave you the "ah ha" moment?